# How to retrieve Text from Database using mvc and sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have done the following and it works but, when trying to store the userid into a variable, it doesn't work, because it returns an `int`

```
String UserLogin;
            UserLogin = "SELECT UserId FROM UserMemberShip,AspNetUsers WHERE UserMembership.UserId = AspNetUsers.Id AND AspNetUsers.Email = '{0}'";
            String.Format(UserLogin,UserLogin,model.Email);
            int a = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(UserLogin);
```

I only need the UserId. How can I get it?

Comment: your query will not work - ("SELECT UserId FROM UserMemberShip,AspNetUsers") it's not correct - use joins.

Comment: Try `int a = db.Database.SqlQuery<int>(UserLogin).FirstOrDefault();` but as @free4ride noted, you syntax does not look correct

Comment: if you are using EF why don't you use it? sth like:
  int id = DBContext.AspNetUsers.Single(user => user.Email == "your variable with email here").Id;

Comment: Please don't do a string.format to build your SQL query. Either use EF as others have said or use parameterized SQL to prevent SQL injection attacks on your system!